# How do I display an image on a webpage from a network location?

Tags: asp.net, iis, iis-7.5

I have a web application that will be used internally that points to images on a network drive.

It works when I test it in VS, but the images don't load once published.

I'm sure it's a setting in IIS but I can't figure out what it is.

Each computer is already logged into the domain, and those who have access should be allowed to view the image.

I tried changing the authentication to impersonate, but no luck.

Any ideas?
Thanks

Comment: It would be helpful if you showed an example of one of the Images in code / markup, and then show how the rendered HTML looks when run from VS, and when run from the published site.  Looking at the difference between the two will probably clarify what the problem is.

Comment: It's just an image tag `<img src="//network-share/image.jpg" />`  Nothing special.  It's not a server control so the rendering of the tag doesn't change.

Comment: So that is exactly what it looks like in your ASPX page, and in the browser's "view source" (locally and published)?  Does it behave differently in different browsers?

Comment: Yes, it's an html tag. Unless it says `runat=server` the tag renders the exact same.

Comment: Also asked here: http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/52608/how-do-i-configure-iis-7-5-to-allow-using-a-network-share-as-an-image-src

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it should be answered on webmasters stackexchange.

Comment: @EricBrown, if you look at the answer I submitted, you'll find that the answer was actually was code related.  The question can be reworded for better searching.  I fell into the trap of trying to cure the symptom instead of the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up fixing the issue by changing the way the images are loaded.  Rather than using a network path as the src, I switched to using a generic handler to render the image.

So, now the image tag looks like

```
<img alt="Item Image" src="/ImageHandler.ashx?f=100" />
```

And the images are loaded in the handler with the following code.

```
public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
{
    var f = Convert.ToString(context.Request.QueryString.Get("f"));
    var path = string.Format("//network-share/images/{0}.jpg", f);
    var image = Image.FromFile(path);
    context.Response.Clear();
    context.Response.ClearHeaders();
    image.Save(context.Response.OutputStream, ImageFormat.Jpeg);
    context.Response.ContentType = "image/jpeg";
    HttpContext.Current.ApplicationInstance.CompleteRequest();
}
```

While I still want to figure out the permissions issue, this is a better overall solution.  Since pointing to a file location seems to have cross browser compatibility issues, which you won't have here.

Comment: Did you try enabling the option in my answer?

Comment: Not yet, but I will definitely try, and if it works I'll mark it as answered in the other thread.

Comment: Thanks - also take a look at the accepted answer in the linked question there too.